# how to assign elements of one array to another array in php

Tags: php

i retrieved data from mysql table in php

```
  $array2=array(); while($q1=  mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{    print_r($q1);
    $array2[]= $q['user_id'];
}
```

the print_r($q1) will output this

```
Array ( [user_id] => 1 ) Array ( [user_id] => 2 ) Array ( [user_id] => 4 )
```

.
Now i want to assign these values into another array i.e

```
 $array2[]=$q['user_id'];
```

but when i echo $array2 this gives me result otherthan $print_r($q) i.e

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

my question is how can i get the value of [user_id]=>4 from this array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$q` is different from `$q1`..

You need:

```
$array2[]= $q1['user_id'];
```

It should actually be throwing a warning about `$q['user_id']` not being defined.  Do you have [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on?